# Sharing to Facebook generates Spam Warning on users Facebook account

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8

We are sharing to Facebook on Windows Phone 8 using http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/

This sometimes generates a Spam Warning for the user securing their Facebook account and they need to validate it from their Facebook to resolve it.

We have a valid Facebook App ID that is used for iOS and works well there. Also it is only some users that is affected by this issue.

After the user verifies the account everything works fine but should not be getting this warning in the first place.

The question is what could be causing Facebook to believe the posts is Spam? Ideas?